# Adding Existing Entities to New Object when Inserting Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am having an issue where when I try to insert a new parent object which references a number of existing entities into mydb using entity framework 6 it inserts the entities rather than linking them?

I have the following class (reduced for brevity);

```
public partial class Shipment
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shipmentid")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ShipmentDate { get; set; }
    public string Carrier { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Device> Device { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShipmentType")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shipmenttypeid")]
    public int? ShipmentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ShipmentType ShipmentType { get; set; }

}
```

Now as you can see i has a 1 to many relationship with a list of devices.

I want to create a new instance of a Shipment, but I need to linkup x number of existing devices.

I create the object and then pass it across to my web api using post. I have debugged and the device list is being passed across ok.

I insert using a generic repository;

```
    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _dbset.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and my webapi method call this using the following;

```
_Service.Insert(shipment);
```

When Building the object I simpyly

```
var shipment = new Shipment();

var device1 = GetDeviceFromWebApi; //psuedo
var device2 = GetDeviceFromWebApi; //psuedo

List<Device> deviceList = new List<Device>();
deviceList.Add(device1);
deviceList.Add(device2);

Shipment.Device = deviceList;
```

I've taken a screenshot of a simple example which shows a single device being passed across. This is in the POST of the webapi method.

[image: ScreenGrab of Devices passed to api]

Is there any way I can mark the devices as existing and tell EF not to update (I suppose maybe if the Device.ID is null or empty?)

Can anybody help please?

EDIT 1

In respose to CodeCasters answer

```
public override void Insert(Shipment entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    foreach (var device in entity.Device)
        if (device.ID != null && device.ID > 0)
            _context.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    _dbset.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Please note the difference is I have used .State instead of EntityState as this did not exist in the interface for me.

However when I try to insert get the following error?

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Vehicle.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Device.VehicleId' on the other end.

Now in this case I have a foreign key set up on the device. and when the device is pulled from the database the vehicle class type is populated but not the FK int (using the following;)

```
public int? VehicleId { get; set; }
public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how I do this now? do I physically need to get Vehicle.Id and assigned it to VehicleId?

Comment: Do you want the devices to be updated as well from that POST, or do you only want to create a link?

Comment: @CodeCaster I want it to be flexible ideally. I this instance they will more than likely exist in the db. So I'd just like to create the link to them and not insert.